# Domain In s3 Bucket Name Errors Gulp-AWSPublish

Tags: amazon-web-services, gulp

I'm using Gulp-AWSPublish to upload my site to a bucket with a domain in it and I'm receiving an error when I execute the task. If I change the bucket name to one without a .com, it works fine.

```
var publisher = awspublish.create({
    "params": {
        "Bucket": "mydomain.com"
    },
    "accessKeyId": "...",
    "secretAccessKey": "..."
});
```

Here's the official error:

```
[23:33:32] Using gulpfile ~/WebstormProjects/redirectPage/gulpfile.js
[23:33:32] Starting 'deploy'...

/Users/coty/WebstormProjects/redirectPage/node_modules/gulp-awspublish/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:30
throw err;
^
301: null
at Request.extractError (/Users/coty/WebstormProjects/redirectPage/node_modules/gulp-awspublish/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:321:35)
at Request.callListeners (/Users/coty/WebstormProjects/redirectPage/node_modules/gulp-awspublish/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
at Request.emit (/Users/coty/WebstormProjects/redirectPage/node_modules/gulp-awspublish/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
at Request.emit (/Users/coty/WebstormProjects/redirectPage/node_modules/gulp-awspublish/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:595:14)
at Request.transition (/Users/coty/WebstormProjects/redirectPage/node_modules/gulp-awspublish/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:21:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/coty/WebstormProjects/redirectPage/node_modules/gulp-awspublish/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /Users/coty/WebstormProjects/redirectPage/node_modules/gulp-awspublish/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/coty/WebstormProjects/redirectPage/node_modules/gulp-awspublish/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:37:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/coty/WebstormProjects/redirectPage/node_modules/gulp-awspublish/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:597:12)
at Request.callListeners (/Users/coty/WebstormProjects/redirectPage/node_modules/gulp-awspublish/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)

Process finished with exit code 8
```

Is there a format for buckets with TLDs?

Comment: You should tell us what the error message or error code is.

Comment: If mydomain.com (or whatever it is in reality) is genuinely an existing bucket in your account then you may want to raise a bug against Gulp-AWSPublish. It may ultimately be a bug in the S3 SDK but I'd start with the gulp library.

Comment: I have this problem when my bucket is in the ap-southeast-2 region. When I create the bucket in us-east-1 it works.